# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Cloudflare DNS Not working

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

I update the Cloudflare DNS `1.1.1.1` via TP link Router it's work perfectly on my Mobile devices & other systems but It does not work perfectly in the system installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Latest Version)
I follow a lot of methods & solutions 
None of them Working
But the Google DNS working Perfectly

I follow this method to Fix but not working

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Oct 28 09:54 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered that problem when I tested Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Ubuntu has a new system to configure the network: Netplan

To configure DNS you must edit the file in the /etc/netplan directory with the name 01-netcfg.yaml

There you should put the following key, under the entry of your device ID.

```
nameservers:
          addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

You can see in the example where the mentioned keys are located, and you can look for more information in the link to Netplan

Example copied from https://netplan.io:

```
network:
  version: 2
  # if specified, can only realistically have that value, as networkd can not
  # render wifi / 3G.
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    # opaque ID for physical interfaces, only referred to by other stanzas
    id0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00: 11: 22: 33: 44: 55
      wakeonlan: true
      dhcp4: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.14.2/24
        - 192.168.14.3/24
        - "2001: 1 :: 1/64"
      gateway4: 192.168.14.1
      gateway6: "2001: 1 :: 2"
      nameservers:
        search: [foo.local, bar.local]
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 11.0.0.1
          table: 70
          on-link: true
          metric: 3
      routing-policy:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/8
          from: 192.168.14.2/24
          table: 70
          priority: 100
        - to: 20.0.0.0/8
          from: 192.168.14.3/24
          table: 70
          priority: 50
```

Comment: This one is Enough?


```network:
  version: 2
  nameservers:
          addresses: [1.1.1.1]```

Comment: It is enough that you add

nameservers:
           addresses: [1.1.1.1]

To your existing file.

Comment: for me no files and folders in the directory `netplan` so what can i do now

Comment: In the original post of your question, you say that you installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 (not updated since previous version)
The Netplan package should be installed and the directory have a file entry.

Try installing Netplan:

apt install netplan.io

Otherwise you can write the file following this short article: https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/9/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux